# Debugging .net core 3.1 library code published on github private nuget repository is broken?

Tags: c#, nuget, asp.net-core-3.1, visual-studio-2022, pdb-files

In the last few days I've battled against an issue with debugging nuget packages that I still wasn't able to solve the way I want.

**All this has been tested with visual studio 2022, updated to the latest version available.**

**We have a .NET 3.1 library published on github (private package).
We consume such library in many .NET 3.1 WebAPI backends that we develop.
We need to be able to debug such library.**
GitHUB doesn't seem to support symbol servers at the moment, so I thought we had these **2 possibilities**:

1. **embed the pdb in the dll: this seemed the most straightforward solution** and was the first I tried. By doing so on the core library, when we import that in a .NET webapi project and inspect the "modules" window, we can see that **symbols for the dll have been loaded correctly**; symbol file column reads: "OurLibrary.dll (embedded)"
2. **include the pdb in the nupkg and then add a piece of code** (found here https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1458#issuecomment-420456386) **in the .csproj of consuming .NET webapi project that ensures that the dll pdb, contained in the nuget package, is copied to the bin folder**. Also in this case, inspecting the modules window, **it looks that the symbols have been loaded from metadata** (which I guess is the pdb file itself).

**STILL**, in both cases, **if the project is running**, when I try to set a breakpoint in the Startup.cs file of the consuming WebAPI project, and **step into an IServiceCollection extension method, which is defined in the library**, I'm able to do so, but **many symbols used in that file** (referring to **PUBLIC types** defined in the library, **or from the framework itself**) **are white, and I can't explore them** by doing "go to definintion".
Instead, if I try to peek at the source code of the extension method mentioned before, **when the project is not running, I'm able to peek at code by doing "go to definition" without issues**. So, I set a breakpoint..

[image]

Then, when I launch the project:

[image]

you can see that it's a different "SessionFactory" file, and all the symbols have become white. **If I try to go back to the original file** (with all the types correctly resolved by intellisense), **and set a breakpoint inside it, visual studio automatically switches to the other file** (with "broken" intellisense) and sets the breakpoint there, which is very frustrating..

At the moment the only solution that really behaves the way I want requires me to remove the library nuget package from the project and reference the library as an "Existing project" inside the solution. By doing so everything works perfectly (of course, now library source code is part of the project) but of course seems wrong / time consuming / error prone.

Somebody is able to shed some light on what is going on? Thanks

**EDIT: FURTHER DETAILS FOR USER @Transformer**

I tried your suggestion to include the supplied code in .csproj of both the library and the consuming application:

By doing so in the library .csproj, it contains these settings related to PDB generation, in a property group:

```
<EmbedAllSources>true</EmbedAllSources>
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>portable</DebugType>
<AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>.pdb</AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
```

It also includes this, outside of the property group:

```
<Target Name="AddReferenceRelatedPathsToCopyLocal" AfterTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences">
<ItemGroup>
<ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="@(_ReferenceRelatedPaths)" />
</ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Unfortunately, by doing so, the pdb doesn't seem to be included in the nupkg. Instead, if I add the following (a setting I've already found in the past):

```
<AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>$(AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder);.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>
```

then the pdb is included in nupkg, but still, I experience the same debugging problem in the consuming library, even if I add the code you supplied to the consuming library as well...any other idea?

Thanks a lot for your kind help

Comment: Try to add [SourceLink](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink) to your project, it will give you the ability to automatically download the correct version of the source code while debugging. Make sure to embed the symbols. Also, I'd suggest building the preview version of the nuget in Debug and only the final version in Release. Only this way your pdb's will match the source code, otherwise, because of optimizations performed by release build it will be impossible to view many of the variables values in the debugger, and also F10 will bring you to the wrong line in many cases.

Comment: As stated in the question, unfortunately GitHUB doesn't seem to support symbol servers at the moment, and the nuget pkg is hosted on github so..:(

Comment: That's why I said to embed the symbols into dll

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably because the nuget packages are built with Release configuration which optimizes out the symbols. One way you can debug the package itself is if you open the project (from which you deploy the nuget), build it with Debug configuration, then copy the dll and pdb file into the bin\Debug\ folder of your consumer app. Then start the consumer app with no debugger attached, after it starts, you can attach your nuget project to that process, and your nuget code breakpoints will be hit.

[image]

Comment: Hi. I just checked your solution, which unfortunately doesn't seem to be working: The nuget package has been build with the debug configuration, and the pdb file is present in the nupkg, in the same folder as the dll. Moreover, I tried to launch the consuming project without a debugger after copying dll and pdb (which were already both present, with exactly the same size) and then attach the debugger from the library. The debugger attaches correctly but refuses to hit any breakpoint (with error: The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document).

Comment: Is your program executing code from that dll after you replaced it manually in the bin\debug folder, without crashing?

Comment: Note that when you start your consumer app, it may trigger another build, which will overwrite the dll that you copied manually, so you need to copy it after you built the consumer app.

Comment: Well, you are right. The dll got overwritten each time I launched the consuming project, even without the debugger attached. I had to change the option "On Run, when projects are out of date" -> "Never build" in "Projects and Solutions -> "Build And Run" in options. I thank you for your help but honestly it's easier to remove the nuget package reference from the consuming project and just add the library as a different project in the solution. Still, I'm wondering why this isn't working the same way when the .pdb and the dll comes from the nupkg...

Answer (score 1):

###### Hello, from what I can see - that's because `the embedded files are not copied to local`, please try this in your `cs.proj` file and paste your comments

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>.pdb</AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="AddReferenceRelatedPathsToCopyLocal" AfterTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="@(_ReferenceRelatedPaths)" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

---

Question from Carlo Arnaboldi : Where does this go?
Update: These are settings that go into the .proj file.

You you to do this in your `nuget pacakge` && your `consuming project` to see the `pdb` for symbol debugging

Also delete you old pdbs - exist visual studio/code and then delete the `bin` and `obj` folders

Comment: Last year, I had similar issue and this one was the fix

Comment: Hi. You haven't stated it but I suppose that the above code should be included in the consuming project right? So, I tested it by doing the following: -publish a new version of the library, setted up in such a way that the pdb file is present in the nupkg (this was already working). Then, I updated the library nuget package in the consuming project, added the code you provided in the project.cs and rebuild the project. Unfortunately the pdb files are not copied along with the dll during build. Anyway, I already had found a different piece of code which ensures that the pdb files are copied

Comment: and you can find that piece of code at this address: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1458#issuecomment-420456386 . After doing so, even if I see both the pdb and the dll of the library in the bin folder of the consuming project upon build, I still experience the same problem with the "white symbols". The strange thing is that If I try to inspect such library files while the consuming project is not running (by exploring a couple of library methods in the startup of the consuming project) I can see that all the symbols are resolved, but the explored file has the suffix "[from metadata]"

Comment: Then, I can even set some breakpoints in such files with [from metadata] suffix, but when the project is lauched, another file (without that suffix) opens automatically, and the breakpoints are "moved" there. That file is identical but the symbols are white..so not resolved :( This while the "module" window says that the symbols have been loaded for the library..

Comment: Hi @Transformer , I edited the question and provided further details at the beginning, about your other comments related to your proposed solution. Maybe you're able to help?